# ImageMagick open and write image with qt ans magick++

Tags: c++, qt, visual-c++, qt4, imagemagick

Im using Magick++ Library with Qt

Im using the following code to read and write an image:

```
  Image image;
  image.read(qPrintable(f.absoluteFilePath()));
  image.addNoise(GaussianNoise);
  image.magick("png");
  image.write("image_name");
```

Where f.absoluteFilePath is the absolute path for my image
Example: /Users/user/Desktop/test/P1030673.jpg

After the completion of the code, I cannot locate the image named 'image_name'.
I looked into the folder of the first image '/Users/macmini/Desktop/test/' and its not there
I tried to search the image, but it seems is not in my computer.

Where do I go wrong?
How can I save the image in my computer?
is there any way to specify the path that I want the image to be saved?

Thank you

Comment: Does the reading work? Also, there is probably a way to check for errors during write().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For everyone who might have tha same problem:
Imagemagick will save the images inside the .app bundle

You will not be able to find the image files unless you specify a path inside the read() function

I noticed the following by checking the size of my .app file
It was increased everytime I was trying to save images.

Comment: This problem seems to be specific to OSX. Maybe you should file a bug report on imagemagick.

Answer (score 2):

You should find the file saved in the current working directory. If you want to save it elsewhere give an absolute path.

Comment: what is meant be current working directory?
- I have the Magick++ library folder
- The directory where my Qt project is based
- The directory where the qt project goes when its running
- and the directory where the images reside
How do I give an absolute path?

Thanks for the answer

Comment: If you are starting the program from a menu or an application link from the desktop the cueernt working directory will be your home directory unless you have another working directory defined in the link. If you are starting the program from a shell the the current working directory is the directory you are "in" when you start the program.

Comment: An absolute path is any path starting with "/"

Comment: The problem is related to imagemagick. Of, course I know what current working directory is but I wasnt able to find any files there